# What is the best way to use TYPO3 FrontendUsers in the Extension Builder?

Tags: typo3

When creating an extension dealing with frontend users, what is the best way to use them? So far I have been extending it, but I was asked to find out which is better

Create a new model and add all of the properties, then extend existing model class with:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser
```

Or create a new model that extends that class, and set it with a 1:1 relation to another model that contains its properties?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own model `\Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\FrontendUser`
2. Extend it from `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser`
3. Add your extra fields to your model.
4. Be careful when adding `__construct()` to add `parent::__construct()` in it.
5. Done